# How to import selected contacts to my application?

Tags: java, android, listview, import-contacts

Java Code: 
`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, 
            false);
            Button btnAdd = (Button) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_contacts);
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add Contacts", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return viewRoot;
        }
```

`
Now i want to select the contacts from a list and then add them to a list view.

Comment: What is your programming language? What is target OS (iPhone, Android, WinPhone)? And what have you already tried?

Comment: Android Java & using Android Studio

Comment: Well, now it's better but still unclear. What have you tried so far? Please edit question and add some code you have to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.